# change programmatically the style of my relativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/FragmentSecondary" >
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<RelativeLyout>
```

My style his is style="@style/FragmentSecondary", want to change it programmatically to style=@style/FragmentTrains.
I don't want to rewrite another xml. i need to write it in the code. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016249/how-to-programmatically-setting-style-attribute-in-a-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe you can set the style programatically. To get around this you can create a template layout xml file with the style assigned, for example in res/layout create tvtemplate.xml as with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a template"
        style="@style/my_style" />
```

then inflate this to instantiate your new TextView:

```
TextView myText = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tvtemplate, null);
```

Hope this helps.

Also refer this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241729/android-dynamically-change-style-at-runtime) & [set style from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369504/why-so-complex-to-set-style-from-code-in-android)