# How to set style for spinner programmatically?

Tags: android

I have spinner with a style selection (I set the spinner style in `strings.xml`) and it's works well if I set the style in `main.xml`. But I want to know how to set the style programmatically in which the style already defined in `strings.xml`.

Refer my code below

**main.xml:**

```
      <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/PassengersSpinner1"
         android:layout_width="100dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:layout_span="3"
         android:layout_marginTop="6dp" 
         style="@style/SpinnerStyle" />
```

**strings.xml:**

```
 <style
    name="SpinnerStyle" 
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner">     
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_default</item>            
 </style>
```

Now, I want to know that how can I set this `strings.xml` programmatically without `main.xml`?

Answer (score 2):

From all my reading, you cannot do it, because the style has to be set *before* the view is created.

You **can** do it if you create the view in code (since then you can set the style before creating the view).

If you want to do that, a good example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8369504/1105376).  Both the question and the answer give you methods to achieve your goal.