# How can I programatically set the theme of a spinner to Holo Light?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-theme

I want to set the theme of the spinner widget to Holo.Light, without using xml. Say in xml layout, you would write :

```
style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner"
```

How can I do it programatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: set view style programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723881/android-set-view-style-programatically)

Comment: or a duplicate from [why-so-complex-to-set-style-from-code-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369504/why-so-complex-to-set-style-from-code-in-android)